Contents of visual studio solution file
As part of trying to understand the Visual Studio functionality more, I have been looking at the project and solution files. While I could find good official documentation about the project file, I did not find much detail on the solution file. Is there any source where I can understand the contents of the solution file better?
VisualStudioVersion = 17.5.33530.505
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "ProjectABC", "ProjectABC.vcxproj", "{6C3DACBF-D431-4A0E-B7FC-7F6C5C67CC53}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject

For example, in the section posted above, what exactly does the last line mean? Likewise, there are things like preSolution, postSolution which I do not understand. From the official visual studio documentation, I could see how some of these sections are read but it does not talk much about what it means to have something as part of these.
In general, any information that could help me understand the solution file better would be helpful. Please share if you know any sources.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629981/whats-the-purpose-of-this-string-in-my-visual-studio-sln-file
